# Integrating static content when testing Gitlab pages with a local Jekyll installation

Tags: gitlab, jekyll, static-content, jekyll-theme, gitlab-pages

I have built a Gitlab Pages site using the [Start Bootstrap Creative](https://gitlab.com/jekyll-themes/creative/) theme. The theme has some static files, which reside in their own directory tree at `static`. When the site is deployed, content placed in `static/foo/bar` is available at `http://example.com/foo/bar`.

Since I don’t want to do try-and-error commits as I am building my pages, I have installed Jekyll locally. However, when I do `jekyll serve`, the static content is missing (or rather, available at `http://127.0.0.1:4000/static/foo/bar` rather than `http://127.0.0.1:4000/foo/bar` where the theme expects it).

I see that the CI script for Gitlab, `.gitlab-ci.yml`, has the following commands:

```
gem install jekyll
jekyll build -d public/
cp -r static/* public/
```

In other words, the `static` tree is copied to its location manually after the Jekyll build.

How can I achieve the same thing when serving the site locally with `jekyll serve`?